# Entity Framework Search Multiple columns with generics

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6

I am trying to accomplish a search feature that is used across multiple controllers in an API. I am currently using a Repository pattern as well. I will only show the relative part of the repository.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T class, IEntity, new()
{
   IQueryable<T> Get(); 
}
```

We have created an API Endpoint that looks something like:

```
public abstract BaseApiController<T>:ApiController where T:class, IEntity, new()
{
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSearchPage(int pageNumber, string searchText)
   {
      var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var query = await Repository.Get().Where(t=>
            properties.Any(prop => prop.GetValue(t,null).ToString().Contains(searchText))
        )
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(query);
   }
}
```

I am getting an error of:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

So, on to my question: How can I search multiple generic columns using this repository?

Comment: All EF queries has to be translatable to sql query statement. Your is certainly not. It is a much more complex task to build dynamic query expression around multiple fields in an entity. Properties of your entity class might be cointerparts of a field, but they are not equivalent. Not any lunq to objects query can be used as EF query.

Comment: @3xGuy I have done something similar in the past with the help of the classes in `System.Linq.Expressions`, but it becomes quite complex if you don't establish constraints from the beginning, like for example, do you also want to perform the search on numeric and date types? if so, what are the rules to tokenize the value of `searchText` as a valid number/date to be search in the underlying db table? if you restrict this to only string fields (varchar, nvarchar) then it becomes simpler to implement.

Comment: Two things: 1) The reason you get error because EF doesn't know how to convert this to SQL: `prop.GetValue(t,null)`. 2) Using `typeof(T)` within a generic method or class means the method is not generic.